# JMeter throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration.setFormatter(Ljava/text/DateFormat;)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

> 2017-09-29 12:39:56,306 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
>   2017-09-29 12:39:56,307 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
>   2017-09-29 12:39:56,312 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration.setFormatter(Ljava/text/DateFormat;)
>     at kg.apc.jmeter.JMeterPluginsUtils.doBestCSVSetup(JMeterPluginsUtils.java:256) ~[jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.3.jar:?]
>     at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector.setupSaving(PerfMonCollector.java:136) ~[jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar:?]
>     at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector.testStarted(PerfMonCollector.java:113) ~[jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.testStarted(ResultCollector.java:355) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
>     at kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector.testStarted(CorrectedResultCollector.java:28) ~[jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.3.jar:?]
>     at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:218) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
>     at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:388) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_65]

Comment: Please paste the code as text into your question then highlight and press Ctrl+K this allows us to copy and paste your code into our IDEs and help identify the problem. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know what code you need to include

Answer (score 2):

As per UBIK LOAD PACK 's answer and Subho comment above:

For Jmeter 3.3 and  jpgc-perfmon-2.1 (latest versions as I write), after the install of the perfmon zip file into Jmeter, you need to:
  - remove the jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.3.jar from the /lib directory 
  - and replace it with  jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.4.jar  (available from Maven Central).

Thanks so much guys! Spent hours on this (I dont have enough reputation to just add a comment to UBIKs answer)

Comment: PS: Not directly related to the problem, but I also removed jmeter-plugins-manager-0.11.jar the perfmon plugin placed in lib/ext without issue.  I am behind a corporate proxy, and having it there was causing a SocketTimeoutException on startup (I don't need the plugin manager in my Jmeter install, so not a problem for me)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a version of Perfmon plugin which is incompatible with Apache JMeter version as per this message:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration.setFormatter(Ljava/text/DateFormat;)

So either update jmeter-plugins perfmon plugin or downgrade your jmeter.

Comment: i have upgraded Jmeter-plugin-cmn-jmeter-0.3 to 0.4 and it started working. Thank you so much .