# Perfmon plugin is not working in Jmeter 5.5

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, perfmon

Ive installed Perfmon in jmeter and ran server agent in server.

When I try to connect it shows the following error:

> `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Org.apache.jmeter.samplers.samplesaveconfiguration.setFormatter(Ljava/text/Dateformat;)`

In some website they specified a need to downgrade jmeter version to 2.2 since server agent is in 2.2.

I think I need of new version of server agent ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JMeter throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration.setFormatter(Ljava/text/DateFormat;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46485264/jmeter-throws-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-jmeter-samplers-samplesave)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place perfmon-2.2.2 jar and jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.4.jar in lib folder
Place server agent-2.2.3 in server and run startAgent.bat file
This will work in jmeter 5.1.1